# How to de-reference an integer element from enum reference?

Tags: rust

This is my code:

```
enum Foo {
  X(i32)
}
fn take(foo: &Foo) -> i32 {
  match foo {
    X(a) => return a
  }
}
```

I'm getting:

```
6 | X(a) => return a,
  |                ^^^^ expected `i32`, found `&i32`
```

What is the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the de-reference operator `*`.

```
enum Foo {
  X(i32)
}
fn take(foo: &Foo) -> i32 {
  match foo {
    X(a) => return *a
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried, but IntelliJ IDEA says "Can't move" and makes `*a` in red color...

Comment: That's odd. It compiles and runs just fine for me in VS Code. Try running it.

Comment: @yegor256 That's an issue with the IDEA Rust plugin, a false-positive error.